# Is a Swift [AnyObject] array variable equivalent to an NSMutableArray?

Tags: nsmutablearray, swift2

Swift offers fairly painless bridging between Swift native types and there equivalent types in Foundation Classes.

Is an array variable [AnyObject] equivalent in with an NSMutableArray?

```
var swiftArray: [AnyObject] = ["one", "two", "three"]

var anNSArray: NSMutableArray = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, no.

There are a number of important differences.

You use the `append()` method to add objects to a Swift array of `AnyObject`. You need to use `addObject()` to add objects to an `NSMutableArray`:

```
var swiftArray: [AnyObject] = ["one", "two", "three"]
//swiftArray.addObject["four"] does not work.  You have to use `append()`

var anNSArray: NSMutableArray = ["one", "two", "three"]
//anNSArray.append["four"] also does not work. You have to use `addObject()`.
```

Another major difference: the Swift array is a value type, and the equivalent NSMutableArray is a reference type. So if you pass around a Swift array variable, you actually make a new copy each time it is passed to another variable.

So this code:

```
var swiftArray: [AnyObject] = ["one", "two", "three"]
var newArray = swiftArray
newArray.append("fortytwo")
print(swiftArray)
/*
Displays "[one, two, three]"
*/
```

(When you assign swiftArray to a new variable newArray, it creates a new mutable array with the same contents. Adding an item to newArray does not affect the contents of swiftArray.)

Wheras this code:

```
var anNSArray: NSMutableArray = ["one", "two", "three"]
var newNSArray = anNSArray
newNSArray.addObject("fortytwo")
print(anNSArray)

/*
Displays 
(
    one,
    two,
    three,
    fortytwo
)
*/
```

(The NSArray is a reference type, so the assignment

```
var newNSArray = anNSArray
```

causes newNSArray to hold a pointer to the existing array, not create a new mutable array. Changing newNSArray changes anNSArray as well, since they are actually the same array.

Another minor difference: The `print` function invokes the `description()` method on each object, and Swift arrays and NSArrays format their description string differently. NSArray's description string is rather JSON-looking, whereas the Swift array's description looks more like the code used to generate the array contents in the first place.